Definition of elementary conditional expectation through measure-theoretic conditional expectation
Suppose $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a random vector, with given probability space $(\Omega\mathcal{F}\mathbb{P})$. The conditional probability and expectation of a random variable (for simplicity, or vector in general) $Y$ given $X$ be denoted as $\mathbb{P}(Y\in B|X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$. My question is the following: do we have, in general, that $\mathbb{P}(Y\in B|X=x)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ coincide with $\mathbb{P}(Y\in B|X)(\omega)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)(\omega)$ for any $\omega\in\{X=x\}$?
Here I am not assuming that $X$ is discrete (in which case it clearly holds), and for example, since it is enough to consider the expectation case, from which the probability case follows, $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\int y dF_{Y|X=x}(y)$. A little issue here could be defining $F_{Y|X=x}$ for continuous random variables that do not have densities, we may assume absolute continuity or mixed random variables, for the sake of simplicity so that $F_{Y|X=x}$ is well defined (it might be well-defined more in general though).
The reasoning I made is the following (take equalities a.s.): by the Factorisation theorem, $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)=f(X)$ for some deterministic function $f$ since the conditional expectation is $X$-measurable. Consider $\omega\in\{X=x\}$. Then $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)(\omega)=f(x)$. Then it seems natural to define $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\mathbb{E}(Y|X)(\omega)$, the gap however is that I do not know how to show that this matches the definition $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\int y dF_{Y|X=x}(y)$.
Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Yes, my question is if it would be consistent to define a version of it that agrees always with $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ on $\omega\in{X=x}$. Essentially, I am not sure if I can just impose this value, since there is also the mixed case where some $x$ may have mass and others may have no mass.

I am not sure what $\mathbb{P}(Y\in B\mid X)(\omega)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)(\omega)$ mean here.

It is standard notation, since usually conditioning on $\sigma(X)$ is denoted just with $X$ for brevity. B just some Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

This answer might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4941270/11867

@JasonSwanson Thank you, that precisely solves it in the one-dimensional case, so I understand that one needs to use some sophistication, that is these kernels, not just the basic definitions. I will look into the theory. Do you agree that then the answer is positive, because the limiting property of the kernel makes it coincide with the conditional density? However, this step becomes rather obscure with vectors. Do you know whether the limiting property survives in higher dimensions?

Yes to the first question. That is something I routinely prove when I teach graduate probability. For the second question, everything works fine in $n$ dimensions. You can use regular conditional distributions on any standard Borel space.

@Mittens You are misunderstanding, it is different: it is clear from the question that I am not asking about the definition, which is what is dealt in your link, but if it can be computed relying on elementary conditioning, and what is precisely the relationship of this connection.
